# How to remove an element from a PHP array if the key equals 'index'?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this `$array` in which the `index` key could appear in any random order:

```
array(4) {
  ["foo"]=> bool(false)
  ["index"]=> bool(false)
  ["bar"]=> bool(true)
  ["biff"]=> bool(false)
}
```

Without adjusting the position of the elements or changing the key or value, how do I remove the `index` element, resulting in a new `$array`?

```
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=> bool(false)
  ["bar"]=> bool(true)
  ["biff"]=> bool(false)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
unset($array['index']);
```

Comment: Ya know, I'm too tired to be working right now. Thanks, folks. =)

Answer (score 4):

```
unset($array['index']);
```

Answer (score 3):

`unset($array['index']);` is what you're looking for. This will work even if there is no 'index' key in the array.